NVM and Node was not able to find in Azure Windows Agent
We are using windows agent which has NVM and two versions of Node JS. When we use this agent in azure pipeline, it was unable to find the NVM. Due to the requirement we don't want to use NodeTool task to install it again as already it has Node JS and NVM. Even we tried to print the entries in environment variable PATH which has the expected entries. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?
